# Localization using knockout.js and Web Api

Tags: localization, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently using Web Api for my service calls and binding the responses via knockout.js. Everything is working great with the exception of localization.

Previously, using MVC3 Razor, I would use the HtmlHelper to fetch the localization text for me eg: `@Html.Resource("File, Key")`

Obviously, with this new approach, I cannot have the service side code fetch happening on the client, so I'll need to fetch all these values from the server before hand.

My question is: How is this being accomplished when using Web Api and Knockout?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you describe you specific problem? From what I about the Web API  it has razor views, that should allow you to generate the HTML you want. If you're looking for an easy code-only way to use resources, take a look at this http://blog.baltrinic.com/software-development/dotnet/t4-template-replace-resxfilecodegenerator I use this approach for one of my own projects, and it works great.

Comment: This is an order submission flow. Some of the content that is loaded is dynamic in nature (such as error messages returned from the service). These messages have substitution params in which we substitute certain text which needs to be localized.

Using web api, I'm not returning a view... but simply the service response in json format. So after this returns, I'll need to get some localized text in certain situations.

Comment: Then take a look at the T4 templates I linked, it'll allow you to obtaint the resource strings using code only (and then return the text in the json response).

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for: [Knockout Localization Binding](https://github.com/tfsjohan/Knockout-Localization-Binding).
Even if you don't want to use the original source, it's pretty simple to build a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at [i18next](http://i18next.com/) 
It provides you with declarative syntax for the html page and can load json resources dynamically.